# How to ask Mathematica to solve a simple modular equation

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What's the most straightforward way to ask Mathematica to find all solutions of an equation like

$$3x + 2y + 4z = 0 \pmod {11}$$

(for instance), where *either* $x$, $y$, $z$ can be considered to be integers in the range $-5\dots 5$,
*or* equivalently they belong to the ring $Z/(11Z)$ of integers modulo $11$?

(I've tried a number of obvious things with no success.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Solve[Mod[3 x + 2 y + 4 z, 11] == 0 &&
      -5 <= x <= 5 && -5 <= y <= 5 && -5 <= z <= 5, Integers]

(*    {{x -> -5, y -> -5, z -> -2},
       {x -> -5, y -> -4, z -> 3},
       {x -> -5, y -> -3, z -> -3},
       ...
       {x -> 5, y -> 5, z -> 2}}    *)
```

(121 solutions)

Answer (score 3):

`Solve[3 x + 2 y + 4 z == 0, Modulus -> 11]` produces `{{z -> 2 x + 5 y}}` (as residue classes modulo 11).

Comment: Yes, multiplying 3x + 2y + 4z = 0 by 3 (in the field Z/11Z) gives -2x + 6y + z = 0, or in other words z = 2x + 5y.

Comment: Which is the set of solutions! Just like linear algebra over the field of real numbers, we have two free variables x and y, and the value of z is uniquely determined by them. In my opinion, this is a much better form than listing the 121 solutions one by one.

Comment: I agree, this is much better than what I proposed.

Comment: I personally prefer `Reduce[]` for this: `Reduce[3 x + 2 y + 4 z == 0, {x, y, z}, Modulus -> 11]`. This highlights the fact that there is a parametric solution.